# Mac OS X and Windows XP VM

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a Windows XP VM setup in my Mac OS X Virtualbox.

I am connected to the internet using a Cat5 cable and not via AirPort.

I am trying to make it, so I can browse the internet on the Windows XP machine, but I cannot seem to manage this.

I have set the network for the VM as `NAT`, `Bridged Adapter` and `Host-only Adapter`, but none of these seems to work when I reboot the VM and enter a URL into IE.

Is there any further configuration I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Please read our FAQ before posting again.

Comment: So OS X can access the internet just fine? NAT should do the trick, but what are your Windows network settings?

Comment: Yes OS X can access the internet just fine (I am posting from my Mac). I have not configured any of the Network Settings in Windows. i thought It'd use the OS X settings.

Comment: What settings does Windows show? Open a command prompt and enter "ipconfig" and it should tell you what settings the interface has. I normally use bridged mode for the least hassles in networking as well, so that the VM shows up as another workstation on the network rather than something that ends up being double-natted to the Internet.